# Define number format in Webi Report 4.1

Tags: business-objects, webi

Is there any option to define a format for the number in Webi Reports?

Thanks

Niki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my question. In WeBI URL, we do not have an option to define a format. We have to do the custom format in WebI Rich Client.

Thanks

Niki

Comment: Custom formatting is not available with the HTML version of Web Intelligence; only in the Java version or Rich Client.

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/04/27/web-intelligence-41-sp3-applet-java-vs-html/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Format Number Option available in WebI.

Comment: Could you please guide me to show Where this format Number Option is available in WebI 4.1 version?

Comment: Right CLick on the Cell containing the number and you'll find it 2nd from the bottom.

Comment: I did the same. I could see Format cell, but not to define a format. Are you saying this in Deski Version or URL?

Comment: Hi Niki....This might be because the column you've selected is a string.either Convert it into an integer at the universe level using CONVERT or CAST or you can convert using ToNumber() function in the webI Report.

Comment: Hi VJAI.. The column which i need to format into  a particular form is in number. In BI Launch Pad, i.e. , in URL Custom Format is not available. It is available only in WebI Rich Client.